# Arabic analyzer Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I'm trying to index an Arabic text file, using the `ArabicAnalyzer` provided by Apache Lucene.  The following code shows what I am trying to do:

```
public class Indexer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String indexDir = "E:/workspace/IRThesisCorpusByApacheLucene/indexDir";
        String dataDir = "E:/workspace/IRThesisCorpusByApacheLucene/dataDir";
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Indexer indexer = new Indexer(indexDir);
        int numIndexed;
        try {
            numIndexed = indexer.index(dataDir, new TextFilesFilter());
        } finally {
            indexer.close();
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Indexing " + numIndexed + " files took "
            + (end - start) + " milliseconds");
    }

    private IndexWriter writer;
    public Indexer(String indexDir) throws IOException {
        Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir));

        writer = new IndexWriter(dir,new IndexWriterConfig
            (Version.LUCENE_45, new ArabicAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_45))
        );
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        writer.close();
    }

    public int index(String dataDir, FileFilter filter)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println(" Dir Path :::::"+ new File(dataDir).getAbsolutePath());
        File[] files = new File(dataDir).listFiles();
        System.out.println(" Files number :::::"+files.length);
        for (File f: files) {
            System.out.println(" File is :::::"+f);
            if (!f.isDirectory() &&
                    !f.isHidden() &&
                    f.exists() &&
                    f.canRead() &&
                    (filter == null || filter.accept(f))) {
                indexFile(f);
            }
        }
        return writer.numDocs();
    }

    private static class TextFilesFilter implements FileFilter {
        public boolean accept(File path) {
            return path.getName().toLowerCase()
                .endsWith(".txt");
        }
    }

    protected Document getDocument(File f) throws Exception {
        Document doc = new Document();

        InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader
                (new FileInputStream(f),"UTF8");
        System.out.println(" Encoding is ::::"+reader.getEncoding());

        doc.add(new TextField("contents",reader ));
        doc.add(new TextField("filename", f.getName(),
                Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new TextField("fullpath", f.getCanonicalPath(),
                Field.Store.YES));

        return doc;
    }

    private void indexFile(File f) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Indexing " + f.getCanonicalPath());
        Document doc = getDocument(f);
        System.out.println(" In indexFile :::::::: doc is ::"+doc+" writer:::"+writer); 
        writer.addDocument(doc,new ArabicAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_45));
    }
}
```

my text file contains  :

> ```
> {سم الله الرحمن الرحيم
> ```
>
> اهلا و سهلا بكم  ، ماذا بعد 
>   كتب يكتب كاتب مكتوب سيكتب }

When run, I get the following results in file _0.cfs: [image: screenshot of _0.cfs]

I get words, but also get undefined characters

What is the problem here?  Why doesn't it show Arabic correctly?

Comment: And why you are dealing with *.cfs files anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be looking at `.cfs` files directly.  The cfs is a compound index file, and is not, in any way, a plain text document.  You are intended to use the Lucene API to search and retrieve data from an index, not just look at the file in an editor.  If you want to know more about Lucene file formats, feel free to look at the [codec documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene40/package-summary.html#Introduction)